# Rails Edit Route not working after upgrade to 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing

I updated from Rails 3.1.3 to 3.2.11

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :resource, :path=> "files" ,:only=>[:show, :edit, :update] do
  end
```

Thus URL for my file edit is like:
    **files/141/edit/**

which used to work with previous rails, However giving error with upgraded one as:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"resources20/resource", :id=>nil}
```

Note the id **nil** above.

Even from **rails console**
Using Rails.application.routes.recognize_path "/files/1/edit" returns me properly:

```
{:action=>"edit", :controller=>"resources20/resource", :id=>"1"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't be coming from your URL, it will most likely be coming from a URL displayed on the edit page. The logs will show exactly what action is being hit by that URL.